# VBA Macro in Word: How to manipulate text at a sub address given the link to it?

Tags: vba

The document I'm working with is full of internal hyperlinks made by Endnote with something like "#_ENREF_76" as the address.  I am trying to write a macro that cycles through all hyperlinks, copies the text at the address in the link and does stuff with it.  Like:

```
For i = ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1
    With ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks(i)
        myText = .get_The_Text_At_The_Address_In_The_Link
        doStuff(myText)
    End With
Next i
```

Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with Word, but this would work if your linked bookmarks actually contain the text you want to grab.

```
Sub Tester()
    Dim h As Hyperlink, b As Bookmark
    For Each h In ActiveDocument.Hyperlinks
        'Debug.Print h.TextToDisplay, h.SubAddress

        On Error Resume Next
        Set b = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks(h.SubAddress)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not b Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print h.SubAddress & " contains '" & b.Range.Text & "'"
        End If

    Next h
End Sub
```